# How to destructure method properties without duplicating defaults?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class:

```js
type FooConfig = { b?: number, c?: number };

class Foo {
    static A({ b = 0, c = 1 }: FooConfig) {
        ...
    }

    static B({ b = 0, c = 1 }: FooConfig) {
        ...
    }

    static C({ b = 0, c = 1 }: FooConfig) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm destructuring the config in each method and assigning default values. However, I'm duplicating all of the default values. If I want to update a default value, I need to go back through each method and update. Is there a canonical way to express this while avoiding duplication?

I thought maybe doing something like this:

```js
class Foo {
    static A({ b, c }: FooConfig = { b: 0, c: 1 }) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But calling the method with one property results in the other property being undefined.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't offer any specific syntax for this, just basic JS. As you've seen, providing a default for the whole object behaves differently to providing defaults for each destructured property.

Comment: I'd probably give up on destructuring assignment in the parameter and instead move it into the body like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nly7xm), and you can modify the default in one place.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?